# Is it possible that sine of any natural number is rational?

Tags: number-theory

Namely, is the following proposition true?
$$``n\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow \sin n\notin\mathbb{Q}"$$

Comment: Does $\mathbb{N}$ contain $0$?

Comment: Likely no, @Fimpellizieri

Comment: Demonstrably, no.  But it's "sine," not "sinus."

Comment: The answer is no. There is a theorem called Niven's Theorem, which demonstrates this result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven's_theorem

Comment: No. $\mathbb{N}$ does not contain zero.

Comment: Don't you call it $\mathbb{N}^*$ ? Niven's theorem appears to be a different problem since angles are in degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not unless you count $\sin 0 = 0$.

One definition of the sine (not "sinus" in English) is $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$, so the fact that a nonzero integer can't have a rational sine is implied by the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lindemann-WeierstrassTheorem.html), which states that e raised to any nonzero [algebraic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicInteger.html) power isn't algebraic.  The algebraic numbers contain the rational numbers, as well as any algebraic number multiplied by $i$ and both the real and the imaginary parts of any nonreal algebraic number.  If $\theta$ is rational, therefore $i\theta$ is algebraic, so $\cos\theta$ nor $\sin\theta$ can't both be algebraic, leaving the possibility that $\sin\theta$ is algebraic and $\cos\theta$ isn't.  This is belied by the fact that $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$, so $\sin\theta$ can't be algebraic, and therefore can't be rational.

Comment: If a number is non algebraic, does it follow that both its real and imaginary parts are non algebraic?

Comment: At least one, not necessarily both.

Comment: Yes, so how do we conclude that $\mathrm{sin} \theta$ is non algebraic from the fact that $e^{i \theta}$ is non algebraic?

Comment: Because the definition of an algebraic number is that it's the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients; by replacing x with (a+bi), you get two new polynomials, one real and one imaginary, that both must equal zero, both with integer coefficients.

Comment: Sorry - looking at this thread, I suddenly realize my answer was lousy.  I'll fix it.